# Segues from a subView

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, ios5, uistoryboard

Just trying to teach myself storyboarding and have run into a question I was hoping people may have an answer to.

I wanted to create a reusable upper toolbar so that in case I ever had to change it, it would update all of my scenes.  I created a sized ViewController in my storyboard.  I then load it into a subview of each of my scenes using the menu's identifier.  THat seems to work pretty well (although, feel free to tell me that's the wrong way to do it).

Here's where the problem starts.  On that top toolbar, I have a UIButton which I connect to another sized ViewController in my storyboard as a popover.  Basically, a drop down menu.  If I just load up the top toolbar, works fine.  If I connect just a regular button to that popover scene using a segue, that works too.  If, however, I try to click the button and follow the segue while the toolbar is within a subView I crash with EXC_BAD_ACCESS.  I presume I'm not allowed to spawn a popOver from a subView or follow a segue within a subview?  The latter seems wrong since you effectively do that with any UI object.

How else should I handle this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using a UINavigationController and setting the toolbar to include your UIButton (as a UIBarButtonItem). If you have any trouble "keeping track" of the toolbar or button you can subclass UINavigationController, add the UIButton (or entire toolbar) as a property of the subclass, and access it from any subsequent view through the self.navigationController property (might violate strict OO, but you could use a protocol).

As for the popover, I think you're OK on iPad but not on iPhone. There are custom projects on github to implement UIPopoverController, and indeed the Facebook app makes use of a custom popover for notifications in their app. iPhone raises an exception if you try to show a UIPopoverController.